# Efficiency of SQL Cursor to Run Financial Calculation

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

I have written a fairly large stored procedure to run some calculations using a couple of different datasets.  Currently it uses a cursor to loop through the results and run some calculations.  It then stores those "previous rows" calculations and then uses those on the next iteration.  I've read to avoid cursors when possible for performance.  I want this to scale as well as it can and just wanted any suggestions if possible.  I've played around with thinking maybe the LAG function could help here but haven't had any luck. I'm using MS SQL hosted in Azure. Here is the current procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[spCreateAmoritzation]
@AccountNumber varchar(50)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY  
    DECLARE @principalRemaining DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE @AmtFinanced decimal(10,2);
    DECLARE @APR decimal(27,25);
    DECLARE @ContractDate datetime;
    DECLARE @PrincipalBalance decimal;
    SET @PrincipalBalance = 5000;

    SELECT Top 1 @AccountNumber = AccountNumber, 
                 @AmtFinanced = AmtFinanced, 
                @APR = APR, 
                @ContractDate = ContractDate
    FROM Account s
    WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber


    DECLARE @interestRemaining DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE @principalCollected DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE @interestPerDiem DECIMAL(10,9);

    SET @interestRemaining = 0;
    SET @principalCollected = 0;
    SET @principalRemaining = @AmtFinanced;


    DECLARE @RowCount INT;

    IF @APR > 1
           SET @APR = @APR/100.00;

    DECLARE th_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD  FOR 
    SELECT EffectiveDate, Principal,Type
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE AccountID = @AccountNumber
    ORDER BY Id ASC

    OPEN th_cursor


    DECLARE @EffectiveDate datetime;
    DECLARE @Principal DECIMAL(18,2);
    DECLARE @Type varchaR(50);
    DECLARE @interestEarned decimal(10,2);


    FETCH NEXT FROM th_cursor   
    INTO @EffectiveDate, @Principal ,@Type

     IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
     BEGIN
        CLOSE th_cursor;  
        DEALLOCATE th_cursor;  
           RETURN    
        END


    DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    AccountNumber varchar(50),
    PaymentDate datetime,
    Payment decimal(18,2),
    Type varchar(30),
    InterestPerDiem decimal(10,9) null,
    InterestEarned decimal(10,2) null,
    InterestRemaining decimal(10,2) null,
    PrincipalCollected decimal(18,2) null,
    PrincipalRemaining decimal(18,2)
    )

        INSERT INTO @Table 
            (AccountNumber,Payment, PaymentDate,  Type, PrincipalRemaining )
            VALUES 
            (@AccountNumber, 0, @ContractDate, 'PAYMENT', @principalRemaining) 



        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
        BEGIN  
            SET @interestPerDiem = (@APR/365)  * @principalRemaining  
            SET @interestEarned = ((DATEDIFF(DAY,@ContractDate, @EffectiveDate) * @interestPerDiem) + @interestRemaining)
            IF (@Type = 'PAYMENT')

            BEGIN

                    IF (@interestEarned - @Principal > 0) 
                        SET @interestRemaining = @interestEarned - @Principal;
                    ELSE
                        SET @interestRemaining = 0


                    IF(@interestEarned - @Principal > 0)
                        SET @principalCollected = 0
                    ELSE
                       SET @principalCollected= @Principal - @interestEarned


                    SET @principalRemaining = @principalRemaining - @principalCollected
            END

            IF (@Type = 'PRNCRADJ')
                BEGIN 
                    SET @principalRemaining = @principalRemaining - @Principal
                    SET @interestPerDiem = NULL
                    set @interestEarned = NULL
                    set @principalCollected = NULL
            END

            IF (@Type = 'PRNDRADJ')
                BEGIN 
                    SET @principalRemaining = @principalRemaining+ @Principal
                    SET @interestPerDiem = NULL
                    set @interestEarned = NULL
                    set @principalCollected = NULL
            END


            INSERT INTO @Table 
            (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, Payment, Type, InterestPerDiem, InterestRemaining, InterestEarned, PrincipalCollected, PrincipalRemaining )
            VALUES 
            (@AccountNumber, @EffectiveDate, @Principal, @Type, @interestPerDiem, @interestRemaining, @interestEarned, @principalCollected, @principalRemaining) 

            SET @ContractDate = @EffectiveDate


             FETCH NEXT FROM th_cursor INTO @EffectiveDate, @Principal ,@Type  
        END   


    CLOSE th_cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE th_cursor;  

        INSERT INTO Results
        (AccountNumber, PaymentDate, Payment, Type, InterestPerDiem, InterestRemaining, InterestEarned, PrincipalCollected, PrincipalRemaining )
        SELECT * from @Table;

        UPDATE Calculator
        SET Variance = @principalRemaining, LastCalculated = GetDate()
        WHERE AccountID = @AccountNumber;

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    return
END CATCH


GO
```

Here is sample data from the Transactions table:

```
AccountID   EffectiveDate   Principal   Type
12345   10/3/2013   450.00  PAYMENT
12345   10/30/2013  419.34  PAYMENT
12345   12/2/2013   419.34  PAYMENT
12345   1/17/2014   414.00  PAYMENT
12345   2/12/2014   420.00  PAYMENT
```

Here is sample output from the Results table:

```
AccountID   Payment Type    InterestPerDiem InterestRemaining   InterestEarned  PrincipalCollected  PrincipalRemaining
12345   0.00    PAYMENT NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    10875.82
12345   244.19  PAYMENT 2.976697036 119.07  0.00    125.12  10750.70
12345   244.19  PAYMENT 2.942451863 85.33   0.00    158.86  10591.84
12345   244.19  PAYMENT 2.898972099 86.97   0.00    157.22  10434.62
12345   244.19  PAYMENT 2.855941200 114.24  0.00    129.95  10304.67
```

That output of the function is that it will grab an account and get some basic information like APR, Amount financed, and contract date.

Then it will run a loop through a list of transactions for that account which will include dates and payments.  As it loops through each row from the transactions it will calculate interest and such using APR and a few other metrics.  Ultimately this result set of calculations will be written to a table.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)